# SQL Server - Missing precision on calculating percentage of total using values stored as money

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to calculate a percentage of total dollars using values stored as `money`. I am having issues with the precision of the decimal value being rounded, and sometimes to zero. I am casting the value to `decimal(23,22)`, shown here:

```
CAST(Dollars / (SELECT SUM(Dollars) FROM #TempTable) AS DECIMAL(23, 22)) AS DollarShare
```

An example would be a record having a total sales of $7.00 out of a total spend of $645503.98. The value returned is 0.0000150000000000000000 when it should be 1.084423987594933e-5.

Someone please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Money / Money will return Money.

Convert at least the numerator or denominator (or both) to either a float or decimal

**Example**

```
Declare @num money = 7
Declare @den money = 645503.98

Select AsMoney   = @num/@den
      ,AsFloat   = (@num+0.0)/@den
      ,AsDecimal = convert(decimal(23,22),@num)/@den
```

**Returns**

```
AsMoney AsFloat                 AsDecimal
0.00    0.000010844239875949    0.000010844239875949331869340294385
```

Comment: John you are an amazing human being. I can't believe it was something so simple to fix.

Comment: @PraiseBeExcel I'm sure my wife would dispute that. :)  Happy to help